# Two activities with NFC foreground dispatch issue

Tags: android, nfc, foreground, dispatch

I have two activities A and B. A always starts before B and B uses the dialog theme (this is required and important). Both use the NFC foreground dispatch mechanism, which works pretty well. However, when the orientation changes there is an issue. I enable and disable the foreground dispatch in the onResume and onPause methods, as I should.

What happens:

- A launches, A onResume gets called
- A onPause, B launches, B onResume gets called (everything as expected and it works)
- Orientation change
- B onPause gets called, B launches again, B onResume gets called, A launches in the background again, A onResume gets called, A onPause gets called

--> Now B's foreground dispatch doesn't work anymore.

B's dialog theme is causing this issue as everything works well with a normal theme. Is there a workaround?

**Solution:**

Thanks for the comments, but I found a workaround, which helps. In the onCreate method of activity B I do the following:

```
    /*
     * This workaround is needed as this activity uses the dialog theme. When the background activity uses the foreground
     * dispatch as well, then it breaks this activity's foreground dispatch on an orientation change. 
     */
    mCancelButton.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            NfcForegroundDispatch.setupForegroundDispatch(NfcDetectorActivity.this);
        }
    });
```

As I've said, it's a workaround not a solution.

Comment: Any idea about read NFC tag while phone is Locked?

Comment: NFC hardware is disabled when the phone keyboard lock is enabled

Comment: ot really an answer to your question but couldn't you just lock the applications into one orientation?